# VLC.DotNet.WPF Lib Options keywords

Tags: wpf, libvlc

I have a task to do in which i have to configure VLC player to display Audio/Video content.
Everything is working fine but now i have to set video speed and Fit to Window option while assigning the content to VLControl. I have searched alot but i am unable to find any such help related to this LIB.

Now i want to know what is the Option parameter in vlcControl.MediaPlayer.Play() function?

```
    vlcControl = CreateVLCMediaPlayer();
    vlcControl.MediaPlayer.Video.AspectRatio = settings.AspectRatio;
    vlcControl.MediaPlayer.EndReached += vlcControl_EndReached;
    var options = new[] { "" };
    vlcControl.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri(path), options);
    contentControl.Content = vlcControl;
```

And what are the options strings keywords to send in Play() function. Is there any link where i can find all the related keywords?